# Magento won't run my install script

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, installation

Okay so I am trying to add a field to the registration with my module. Obviously I have to add an attribute. So my "install script" is really just an upgrade to the customer entity. However, the module is enabled and yet when I refresh the front end it will not run my install script. I have put a die at the front to see if its even hitting it and its not.

I have checked about 7 other stack overflow questions and each of the errors was pretty blatant. Things like the config not matching the folder it was in. Using customer_setup as the name. Errors in the setup file. Over and over i've looked at my code and i KNOW im missing something small. Some typo somewhere.....but ive wasted too much time now, so I hand it off to you great people.

Config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <BlizzardLabs_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </BlizzardLabs_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <flavour>
                  <create>1</create>
                  <update>1</update>
                </flavour>
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
        <resources>
            <blizzardlabs_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>BlizzardLabs_Customer</module>
                    <class>BlizzardLabs_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </blizzardlabs_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

BlizzardLabs/Customer/Model/Entity/Setup.php

```
class BlizzardLabs_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup {

  public function getDefaultEntities() {
    $entities = parent::getDefaultEntities();

    // Add flavour to customer attributes
    $entities['customer']['attributes']['flavour'] = array(
        'label' => 'Ice Cream Flavour',
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => true,
    );

    return $entities;
  }

}
```

BlizzardLabs/Customer/sql/blizzardlabs_customer_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
Mage::log('Installing BlizzardLabs_Customer');

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'flavour', array(
    'label' => 'Ice Cream Flavour',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'position' => 1,
));

$attrs = array('flavour');

foreach ($attrs as $item) {
  $attr = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', $item);
  $attr->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'))->save();
}

$installer->endSetup();

echo "information added to database";
```

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for the info....do you think i should move it there instead?

Comment: I would *guess* you'd get a better response there.

Comment: ill keep it up for now....ill put it up there as well. I will just refrain from putting future magento questions here. Thanks

Comment: Checkout this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041783/my-module-installer-doesnt-run-and-doesnt-gets-into-the-resource-table/14045550#14045550

Comment: That was a simple version error. A) This script is not running at all B) I double checked in core_resource and there is no entry for it. Any other modules i have created show up in there just fine.

Comment: Don't use `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` -- that's deprecated. Just `install-0.1.0.php`.

Comment: Actually mysql4-install is not deprecated. The difference is that if it has mysql4 in the name then it is only tested for mysql4 (has direct SQL statements etc). If its just install then this tells people that it is Database Agnostic and will work with any database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. I am not sure if this is a version thing, but for thoroughness I am using magento 1.13.

Here is my issue:

```
<blizzardlabs_customer_setup>
</blizzardlabs_customer_setup>
```

Needed to be:

```
  <blizzardlabscustomer_setup>  
  </blizzardlabscustomer_setup>
```

I of course had to edit my folder to match this. So the new path is `/BlizzardLabs/Customer/sql/blizzardlabscustomer_setup/<file_name>`.

Also, for posterity sake, using "customer_setup" would not work because this would clash with the Magento base class and not run the install script.

I am not sure if this is a magento version issue or something old but you can't have any underscores before _setup. Thanks!

Comment: If you can figure out why it doesnt allow underscores before '_setup' unless you use the <depends> configuration option and add it into your answer (along with my explanation above) I will up-vote your answer and put it as the answer on the question :)

Comment: I actually can not Replicate.
The File gets loaded ( It throws an SQL error cause it was loaded before, but that means it is being called.)
I am not useing
 <class></class>

Answer (score 0):

```
BlizzardLabs/Customer/sql/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

Shouldn't this be (In every module I've written at-least)

```
BlizzardLabs/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

or maybe (Above is likely to conflict with mage_customer anyway)

```
BlizzardLabs/Customer/sql/blizzardlabs_customer_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

Comment: I updated that in the question. Stay tuned for the answer (which i have no figured out). Its a doozie :)